# I cant get through these CakePHP errors

Tags: php, cakephp

i have these codes in my controller and it returns an error.

```
move_uploaded_file($this->request->data['FileUpload']['photo']['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT.'/pictures/sample.jpg');
```

errors:

> Undefined property: FileUploadsController::$request
>
> Trying to get property of non-object

I dont know what to do with this kind of error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In what context is this line? You're going to have to supply some more code

Comment: what do you see for pr($this->request); ..?

Comment: The error means `request` isn't a property of the current object. Have you set up the class correctly? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html

Comment: <?php
 class FileUploadsController extends AppController
 {
  public $name = 'FileUpload';
  function upload(){
   move_uploaded_file($this->request->data['FileUpload']['photo']['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT.'/pictures/sample.jpg');
  }
 }
?>
This is my controller.
btw how can I use the code box thingy where i can put my code on?

Comment: Simply indent your code-lines with at least 1 tab or 4 spaces. Check the orange `?` at the top right of the editor for information on how to use formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please before

```
move_upload_file
```

, write this line:

```
debug($this->request->data)
```

and turn on debug to 2 in Config/core.php